# Upload file to shared dropbox folder

Tags: .net, dropbox, dropnet, sharpbox

I want, from a web application in ASP.NET MVC 2, to upload files sent from users to a mine dropbox shared folder. Is it possible? how to make it? I tried to use DropNet but I'm experiencing some problems and it doesn't seem to make my purpose .. any suggestions? Is sharpbox better?

Many thanks,
Davide

Answer (score 0):

A simple and effective alternative (if you have control of the server) is to have the dropbox client running on the server.

Then you could just upload the files to the dropbox folder on the file system, and the client will take care of the rest, without any need for third (or fourth) party libraries.

Comment: Good one .. but I don't have the control of the server :(